# "Cannot find symbol" on servletContext().getRequestDispatcher

Tags: java, compiler-errors, cannot-find-symbol

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String num = request.getParameter("num");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    sesion.setAttribute("num", num);

    Queries sql = new Queries();
    if (sql.login(num, password)) {
        response.sendRedirect("private.jsp");
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("error", "Error on login");
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
        ServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp"); // This line doesn't working
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

I have a error with `servletContext()`. According Netbeans *Cannot find symbol*. I want to redirect to *login.jsp* with a parameter.

Comment: Try request.getServletContext() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming youre extending `HttpServlet` the servlet context is found using `getServletContext`

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of taking ServletContext ,you can use request scope to
>   forward it to login.jsp below is the one liner code.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request,response);
```